# angular https ionic ios issue Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

HTTP calls are working in ionic ios with angular HTTP, HTTPS calls were showing issue like this

> Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. 
>     You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be 
>     “xxxxxxxxxx.com” which could put your confidential information at 
>     risk

apiService.ts file

```
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private httpIonic: HTTP) {}

getAllStates(){
    return this.httpIonic.get("https://example.com/states")
}
```

And I am calling from another ts page like

```
this.apiService.getAllStates().subscribe((data) => {
    this.allStates(data);
});
```

Comment: I think you need to add proper ssl certificate for this. Have you enabled SSL inning for API call ?

Comment: Try https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Comment: hi, Khurshid when I try the ionic native HTTP the response was in the different format.

Comment: hi code changer, How to enable SSL pinning for API call